# Why is variable my batch file not working?

Tags: batch-file

i wrote

```
@echo off
SET /p filevui = FileName: 
echo %filevui%
```

and it says

> '%filevui%' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

pls help me

Comment: avoid spaces in assignment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET /P filevui=Filename:
echo %filevui%
```

Comment: thanks that really helps me